# How to set shell in module user via registered variable?

Tags: ansible

To disable logins for `root` I would like to set its shell to the path of `nologin`, which is determined by a command.

The command module registers the variable properly:

```
- name: Get nologin path
  command: which nologin
  register: nologin
- debug:
    var: nologin
```

Debug info:

```
ok: [192.168.178.25] => {
"nologin": {
    "changed": true, 
    "cmd": [
        "which", 
        "nologin"
    ], 
    "delta": "0:00:00.001612", 
    "end": "2019-08-26 11:23:41.764847", 
    "failed": false, 
    "rc": 0, 
    "start": "2019-08-26 11:23:41.763235", 
    "stderr": "", 
    "stderr_lines": [], 
    "stdout": "/usr/sbin/nologin", 
    "stdout_lines": [
        "/usr/sbin/nologin"
    ]
}
```

}

But when I use the user module it takes the registered variable as a string:

```
- name: Disable root
  user:
    name: root
    shell: nologin.stdout
    state: present
```

Result in `/etc/passwd`:

```
$ cat /etc/passwd
root:x:0:0:root:/root:nologin.stdout
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a variable, to use it you need to put in jinja2 template `{{ }}` and inside `" "` as it is required by YAML:

```
shell: "{{ nologin.stdout }}"
```

Ref:

- https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#using-variables-with-jinja2
- https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#hey-wait-a-yaml-gotcha